# What is the cycle for Django's single Function Based Views(FBV) handling both GET and POST requests for this code?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, http-post, http-get

I have been trying to get my head around the views and web requests but, couldn't understand how the below code works internally and couldn't figure out how the cycle of request-response works for this code.

```
def todos_add(request):
    form = TodoForm(request.POST or None) #This is Django's in-built Form instance
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/') #redirects to the homepage
    context = {"form" : form}
    return render(request, "main/todos_create.html", context)
```

`todos_create.html` contains the code for displaying the forms and submitting the data. If the form is valid then it stores it in the database and redirects to the homepage.

Any help or link to the references is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `request.POST or None` is a trick to avoid having a `if request.method == 'POST'` check. See [this blog post](https://www.pydanny.com/easy-form-views-controversy.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form = TodoForm(request.POST or None)` Whole logic happens here.
Whenever the view is called, it checks if there is any `POST` data, if it is the request is considered as `POST` request if there is no data submitted on the request it is considered a `GET` view.